# Rails4: How to display the data in has_one and belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Although what I'd like to do is to display `name` in details table, `#<Details:0x44e5f00>` is displayed.
How should I modify my code?

\db\schema.rb

```
  create_table "details", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "title_id"
    t.integer  "day"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "detail"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "title", force: true do |t|
    t.date     "title_date"
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "title_id"
    t.integer  "day"
    t.integer  "category"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "contents"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

\models\title.rb

```
    has_one :details
```

\models\detail.rb

```
    belongs_to :title
```

\views\titlees\show.html.erb

The following is the concerned line.
`<%= Detail.find_by(title_id: (params[:id]), day: inx) %>`

```
<% @article = Article.where(title_id: (params[:id])).order(day: :asc) %>

<div class="row">

  <% for inx in 1..@article.maximum(:day) %>

    <div class="day">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>Day <%= inx %>&nbsp;&nbsp;</h3>
          </div> <!-- md12 -->
        </div> <!-- row -->

        <% @article.where(:day => inx).each do |d| %>
          <div class="row">
              <div>
                <strong><%= d.title %></strong>
                <div class="row">
                    <%= d.contents %>
                </div> <!-- row -->
              </div>
          </div> <!-- row -->
        <% end %>

        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <%= Detail.find_by(title_id: (params[:id]), day: inx) %>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- day -->
    <br>
  <% end %> <!-- for -->

 </div> <!-- row -->
```

Comment: Please refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/. You are violating almost all existing conventions and rules of Rails framework.

Comment: Or you could install https://github.com/railsbp/rails_best_practices to check your code, then refer to guides.rubyonrails.org

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring that you are violating all the Rails conventions, here is what I will suggest

first change this

```
has_one :details
```

to this

```
has_one :detail
```

and than in your views update your code like this

```
<% @article = Article.includes(:detail).where(title_id: (params[:id])).order(day: :asc) %>

<div class="row">

  <% for inx in 1..@article.maximum(:day) %>

<div class="day">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Day <%= inx %>&nbsp;&nbsp;</h3>
      </div> <!-- md12 -->
    </div> <!-- row -->

    <% @article.where(:day => inx).each do |d| %>
      <div class="row">
          <div>
            <strong><%= d.title %></strong>
            <div class="row">
                <%= d.contents %>
            </div> <!-- row -->
          </div>
      </div> <!-- row -->
    <% end %>

    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <%= @article.detail.name %>
      </div>
    </div>

</div> <!-- day -->
<br>
<% end %> <!-- for -->

</div> <!-- row -->
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code almost correct, you only missed the `name` attribute,
you have to call the name attribute after you got the record from database if you wanna display it

e.g. : 
`@detail = Detail.find_by(title_id: (params[:id]), day: inx)`

Id = `@detail.id`

name = `@detail.name`

```
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <%= Detail.find_by(title_id: (params[:id]), day: inx).name %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and it would be better if you can refactor your code

Comment: Easy but wrong decision. You will face n+1 query problem. Also all queries have to be located in controllers or scopes.

Comment: Yes I know that, but if you read his code, I think you already know that he is new in rails, so let him learn step by step, he will know about n+1 in next time